# synchronizing a async method call and its deletgate call in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading

I want to synchronize an async method call and its delegate call.

For example:

Below *foo* calls *bar* after it completes the operation with a result.

```
//foo is an aync method..resides somewhere in external lib
[myObj foo:self action:@selector(bar:) param1:one param2:two];


// delegate
- (void) bar: (int) value {

    // Do something with the int result

    int result = value;    
}
```

I need to synchronize the execution of both *foo* and *bar*. something like this (without modifying *foo*).

```
-(bool) perform_foo_bar {

   int result = [myObj foo_bar:param1:one param2:two]

   if (result == 1) 
   {
     return true;
   }
   else
   {
     return false; 
   }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this using grand central dispatch(GCD) routines?

Comment: So, what is the problem ?

Comment: i want to synchronize both *foo* and *bar* executions without changing *foo* (from external lib)

Comment: there are not even two same method names in your post... what do you want to synchronise with what?

Comment: *foo* is a main procedure resides in external lib. *bar* is a delegate method tells calling thread that *foo* is done. *bar* is invoked by *foo* after *foo* is done. i want to sync *foo* and *bar*. Basically wait till the execution of *foo* completes and then continue based on result.

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite ambiguous, so I provide a generic solution for you about how you can synchronise multiple threads with the `GCD`. I hope it helps on you and you can insert the idea in your real code.

```
dispatch_group_t _group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(_group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"procedure 1, a long runtime is being simulated in 5 secs, but you can put anything here instead.");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.f];
    NSLog(@"procedure 1 is done...");
});

dispatch_group_async(_group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"procedure 2, a longer runtime is being simulated in 10 secs, but you can put anything here instead.");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.f];
    NSLog(@"procedure 2 is done...");
});

dispatch_group_notify(_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"both procedures have been done.");
});
```